# How to set up an Add To Favorites Button in JS with Materialize and Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebase-realtime-database, materialize

I have been using materialize CSS for buttons on some cards in my application and wanted to create a button that when clicked it adds the user's favorite item to another page that I have in HTML called Favorites.html. I have the index.html file which serves as the homepage, where the cards are placed. The user can pick a card and favorite it and have it stored to the Favorites.html page. I was wondering how to do that using Materialize and JS. We are also using Firebase to serve as the backend and relying on JS version- 9 in the FireStore.

Here is an example of the card setup for the on the index.html page with the button being called favorite-btn.

I have tried putting a link into the "a href" to the favorites.html page and it did take me to the favorites.html page but it did not add it to the favorites.html page that I had set up.

```
index.html
```

```
                <div class = "recipe-img">

                    <img src = "coffee.jpg" alt = "a cup of coffee.">

                    <span class = "category-name">Mine</span>
                </div>

                <div class = "recipe-content">
                    <a href="#" class= "right btn-floating grey"><i class="material-icons">delete_outline</i></a>
                    
                    <h2>Americano<a href="#" class="right favorite-btn btn-floating red pulse">
                        <i class="material-icons">favorite</i></a></h2>

                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem, ip``sum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.

                        orem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.orem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.  Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    </p>
                </div>
```